# opencv and projection value

Tags: c++

hi i would like to use height projection to choose between some area detection the area that i like to show her ,what i can add to my code to showing only the binary image that have two peaks of white color?links of picture :

Comment: If you want to add an image, you need to upload it to an external site (for example, imgur.com). Then copy the direct link and paste it here. Do it exactly like this (without the stars):
!*[A name]*(url of image)

Comment: is the link of second image ,so like in the two picture if the image contain one rows of white pixel they have one peak if they contain two rows of white pixels  they have  two peaks ,so i like to add to my code some loop  like this(if image graphe contain +/- two peaks it's the one that i need and show it in the window if not don't show her

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I misunderstood the question. Do you mean: if a row contains X blocks of white, the graph should have a peak of length X?

Comment: it crach the program when i try with this

Answer (score 0):

The following code is based on some assumptions about your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// src is 32bits
IplImage* src_original = cvLoadImage("picture.jpg",1); 

//convert to grayscale! (very important)
IplImage *src = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src_original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor( src_original, src, CV_RGB2GRAY );

// release the original image
cvReleaseImage(&src_original );

//paintx, painty son 8bits
IplImage* paintx=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
IplImage* painty=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );

// this is going to set colour to black
cvZero(paintx);
cvZero(painty);


int* v=new int[src->width];
int* h=new int[src->height];

memset(v,0,src->width*4);
memset(h,0,src->height*4);

int x,y;
uchar s;
CvScalar t;

// counts pixels with bright<100 along each column ("black" pixels)
//
// | | | | | | |
// | | | | | | |
// v v v v v v v
for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
{
   for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
   {
    s = (((uchar*)(src->imageData+src->widthStep*y))[x]); //changed because of 0xC0000005 return error
    if(s < 100)
    v[x]++;
   }
}

// vertical projection
//( with this code, graphic grows up )
for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
{
    for(y=src->height-1; y >= src->height-v[x];y--)
    {
     t.val[0]=255;
     cvSet2D(paintx,y,x,t);
    }
}

// counts pixels with bright<100 along each row ("black" pixels)
// 
// --------->
// --------->
// --------->

for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
{
  for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
  {
   s = (((uchar*)(src->imageData+src->widthStep*y))[x]);
   if(s < 100)
      h[y]++;
  }
}

// horizontal projection
// graphic grows from right to left
for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
{
    for(x=src->width-1; x>= src->width -h[y];x--)
    {
      t.val[0]=255;
      cvSet2D(painty,y,x,t);
     }
}

cvNamedWindow("projection_vertical",1);
cvShowImage("projection_vertical",paintx);

cvNamedWindow("projection_horiz",1);
cvShowImage("projection_horiz",painty);

// wait for a key
cvWaitKey(0);

// release the image
cvReleaseImage(&src );
cvReleaseImage(&paintx );
cvReleaseImage(&painty );
return 0;
}
```

---

1st Edit

I changed the code to adjust it to the image you've just posted.

---

2nd edit.

Counts blocks of white pixels

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// src is 32bits
IplImage* src_original = cvLoadImage("picture.jpg",1); 

//convert to grayscale! (very important)
IplImage *src = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src_original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor( src_original, src, CV_RGB2GRAY );

// release the original image
cvReleaseImage(&src_original );

//paintx, painty son 8bits
IplImage* paintx=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
IplImage* painty=cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );

// this is going to set colour to white
CvScalar c; c.val[0]=255;
cvSet(paintx,c);
cvSet(painty,c);


int* v=new int[src->width];
int* h=new int[src->height];

memset(v,0,src->width*4);
memset(h,0,src->height*4);

int x,y;
int is_prevwhite; //used to remember a change of colour
uchar s;
CvScalar t;

// counts blocks of pixels with bright>100 along each column ("white" blocks)
//
// | | | | | | |
// | | | | | | |
// v v v v v v v
for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
{
   is_prevwhite = 0;
   for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
   {
    s = (((uchar*)(src->imageData+src->widthStep*y))[x]); //changed because of 0xC0000005 return error
    if(s > 100)
      if (!is_prevwhite){
        v[x]++;
        is_prevwhite = 1;
      }
    else
        if (is_prevwhite)
            is_prevwhite = 0;
   }
}

// vertical projection
//( with this code, graphic grows up )
for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
{
    for(y=src->height-1; y >= src->height-v[x];y--)
    {
     t.val[0]=0;
     cvSet2D(paintx,y,x,t);
    }
}

// counts blocks of pixels with bright>100 along each row ("white" blocks)
// 
// --------->
// --------->
// --------->

for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
  {
   is_prevwhite = 0;
   for(x=0;x<src->width;x++)
   {
    s = (((uchar*)(src->imageData+src->widthStep*y))[x]);
    if(s > 100)
      if (!is_prevwhite){
        h[y]++;
        is_prevwhite = 1;
      }
    else
        if (is_prevwhite)
            is_prevwhite = 0;
  }
}

// horizontal projection
// graphic grows from right to left
for(y=0;y<src->height;y++)
{
    for(x=src->width-1; x>= src->width -h[y];x--)
    {
      t.val[0]=0;
      cvSet2D(painty,y,x,t);
     }
}

cvNamedWindow("projection_vertical",1);
cvShowImage("projection_vertical",paintx);

cvNamedWindow("projection_horiz",1);
cvShowImage("projection_horiz",painty);

// wait for a key
cvWaitKey(0);

// release the image
cvReleaseImage(&src );
cvReleaseImage(&paintx );
cvReleaseImage(&painty );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry A.J it crached when i try with your code ,please i add some picture if you can see them

Comment: It takes the namefile directly. And according to your screenshots: now it counts black pixels, instead of  the white ones; graphics grows the opposite way ( ^ and < ); and the colour is reversed (the more black pixels there are along a column/row, the more is the length of the white line in the projection)

Comment: but i need to count white rows in the image

Comment: These are my settings: OpenCV2.2, Code::blocks + MinGW, picture.jpg is in the same directory that executable is, project is in C++ (despite the includes)